# Java: sort one array to another using method and comparator

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, comparator

I'm trying to better understand how the Comparator Interface
in Java interacts with objects and classes.

I have a string array of unsorted words. 
I'd like to copy that array to a second array 
and alphabetize *only* the second array.

When I invoke the Array.sort method 
and pass in the second array and the comparator object as arguments,
*both* arrays end up being sorted alphabetically
and I do not understand why????

Here is an example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // first array is unsorted
        String[] words_unsorted = { "the", "color", "blue", "is", "the",
                "color", "of", "the", "sky" };
        // copy array to another array to be sorted
        String[] words_sorted = words_unsorted;
        // instantiate a reference to a new Comparator object
        Comparator<String> listComparator = new Comparator<String>() { 
            public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
                return str1.compareTo(str2);
            }
        };
        // invoke sort method on words_sorted array 
        Arrays.sort(words_sorted, listComparator);      
        // compare arrays / 
        int size = words_sorted.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {     
            System.out.println(words_unsorted[i] + " " + words_sorted[i]);          
        }       
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
blue blue
color color
color color
is is
of of
sky sky
the the
the the
the the
```

Comment: You don't have two arrays. You have two *references* to the *same* array. In addition, `Arrays.sort()` acts on the array you pass in; you can't pass in one array to `Arrays.sort()` and get a different array out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one array, and `words_sorted` and `words_unsorted` are referring to the same array because you assigned one reference to another here:

```
String[] words_sorted = words_unsorted;
```

You will need a copy of the array itself, not a copy of the reference to the array.  Use [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) to create a new array by copying the old array.

```
String[] words_sorted = Arrays.copyOf(words_unsorted, words_unsorted.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

`String[] words_sorted = words_unsorted;` is simply making `words_sorted` point to the same memory location as `words_unsorted`, meaning that any changes you make to either will be reflected in the other

Instead, you can copy the array using something like...

```
System.arraycopy(words_unsorted, 0, words_sorted, 0, words_unsorted.length);
```